# Exports is read only

Tags: javascript, babeljs, commonjs

I have a utility file `helpers.js`:

```
const func1 = () => {}
const func2 = () => {}

module.exports = {func1, func2}
```

I get access to these helper functions from Node with code like the following:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers.js')
helpers.func1()
```

I also want to access this file from my front end, which is using Babel 7.  If I add this line:

```
import * as helpers from './path/to/helpers.js'
```

I receive the error: `exports is read only`

If I try to change helpers.js to the newer export syntax, I receive the error that the export keyword isn't recognized.

My .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

How can I utilize the same helpers.js file in both Node and Babel 7?

Comment: do you have a babel.config.js file ?

Comment: Yes.

```json
{
  "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Comment: To use `import` don't you have to use `export { func1, func2 }` instead of `module.exports`?

Comment: @Ameer: Maybe, but if I change that, node complains "Unexpected token 'export'"

Comment: I see, try changing `import * as helpers from './path/to/helpers.js'` to `const helpers = require("./path/to/helpers.js")`

Comment: With the change to const I'm still given the error '"exports" is read only'

Comment: Instead of `module.exports = { func1, func2}` do `module.exports.func1 = func1` `module.exports.func2 = func2` then use require in both files

Comment: Same error: exports is read-only

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.  Change my .babelrc presets from

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules":"commonjs"}]
  ]
}
```

There's one line of documentation about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports

Fair warning: I don't understand why this works.